# clear Title from name using R

Tags: r, regex

want to remove title from NameFirst column output will b like Clean_name column.
any suggestions.

```
> df
           NAMEFIRST     Clean_name
1         BHASOTI MS        BHASOTI
2          BHABESHMR        BHABESH
3             RINAMS           RINA
4        SUSHMITAMRS       SUSHMITA
5         ARKADIY MR        ARKADIY
6  PRAMOD TRIMBAK DR PRAMOD TRIMBAK
7          ANDREW MR         ANDREW
8      MICHELLE MISS       MICHELLE
9         DINESHA MR        DINESHA
10        SREEDHARMR       SREEDHAR
11        PANKAJMSTR         PANKAJ
12   SUSHIL KUMAR MR   SUSHIL KUMAR
13          FAZLURMR         FAZLUR
```

Comment: Sounds like a challenge. What have you tried so far?

Comment: please write your expected output. It is really unclear what you are asking aobut.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any useable data. Can be solved like this:

```
column <- c("MICHELLE MISS","PRAMOD TRIMBAK DR")
sub("(\\s*(MR|DR|MISS|MS|MSTR|RS))$","",column)
```

Output:

```
 "MICHELLE"       "PRAMOD TRIMBAK"
```

Comment: Thank u
but in some cases title are with name without space

Comment: This code does not work on when I have let's say `"MR BENEDICT"`  or `"MISSRACHEL"`can we put `^` somewhere to handle these also..

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian There is no hint in the question that the title will be in front of the name.

Comment: I think you should be putting word boundaries around your alternation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not true, `RINAMS` should become `RINA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("RAMOREYDR","SAMUEL MR","MR KOOL","HANDSOMEDR","GELLER DR","SONIA MS"))
df
#         name
# 1  RAMOREYDR
# 2  SAMUEL MR
# 3    MR KOOL
# 4 HANDSOMEDR
# 5  GELLER DR
# 6   SONIA MS

df$Clean_Name <- gsub(" MR|MR|MR | MS|MS|MS | DR|DR|DR ", "", df$name)
df
#         name Clean_Name
# 1  RAMOREYDR    RAMOREY
# 2  SAMUEL MR     SAMUEL
# 3    MR KOOL       KOOL
# 4 HANDSOMEDR   HANDSOME
# 5  GELLER DR     GELLER
# 6   SONIA MS      SONIA
```

Comment: that's a very redundant regex pattern. Also, could it lead to unwanted results as `$` is missing.

Answer (score -1):

This regex will do the trick :

```
df
                name     Clean_name
1         BHASOTI MS        BHASOTI
2          BHABESHMR        BHABESH
3             RINAMS           RINA
4        SUSHMITAMRS       SUSHMITA
5         ARKADIY MR        ARKADIY
6  PRAMOD TRIMBAK DR PRAMOD TRIMBAK
7          ANDREW MR         ANDREW
8      MICHELLE MISS       MICHELLE
9         DINESHA MR        DINESHA
10        SREEDHARMR       SREEDHAR
11        PANKAJMSTR         PANKAJ
12   SUSHIL KUMAR MR   SUSHIL KUMAR
13          FAZLURMR         FAZLUR

df$name_cleaned <- gsub(" *(MS)|(MR)|(DR)|(MRS)|(MISS)|(MSTR)$", "", df$name)
df
                name     Clean_name    name_cleaned
1         BHASOTI MS        BHASOTI         BHASOTI
2          BHABESHMR        BHABESH         BHABESH
3             RINAMS           RINA            RINA
4        SUSHMITAMRS       SUSHMITA        SUSHMITA
5         ARKADIY MR        ARKADIY        ARKADIY 
6  PRAMOD TRIMBAK DR PRAMOD TRIMBAK PRAMOD TRIMBAK 
7          ANDREW MR         ANDREW           ANEW 
8      MICHELLE MISS       MICHELLE       MICHELLE 
9         DINESHA MR        DINESHA        DINESHA 
10        SREEDHARMR       SREEDHAR        SREEDHAR
11        PANKAJMSTR         PANKAJ          PANKAJ
12   SUSHIL KUMAR MR   SUSHIL KUMAR   SUSHIL KUMAR 
13          FAZLURMR         FAZLUR          FAZLUR
```

You can add more elements you want to remove in the regex by separating with `|`